# Extract date from String in scala

Tags: regex, string, scala, date, pattern-matching

I have this text as String `"Report Date 2018-05-04   ""Report Run Date"" 2018-05-05"`

In the above I want to print `2018-05-04`. I am able to do this with `substring` method but that's not right way and need to do regex pattern matching.

Can you please let me know what regex would work in this case.

BTW, I am using Scala

Comment: why can't you just do str.split(" ")[2]?

Answer (score 2):

Something like `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` will do. In Scala:

```
scala> val testString = """"Report Date 2018-05-04   ""Report Run Date"" 2018-05-05""""
testString: String = "Report Date 2018-05-04   ""Report Run Date"" 2018-05-05"

scala> val pattern = "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}".r  // XXXX-XX-XX where X is a number
pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}

scala> (pattern findAllIn testString).toList
res0: List[String] = List(2018-05-04, 2018-05-05)
```

Have a play around on a site like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0qyBRn/1) if you want to learn more about Regex.

Comment: By the way, if you want to match `2018-05-04` literally you can just use the regex `2018-05-04`. None of those are special characters.